In Rust, during sorting in place, will moving elements in a vector becomes expensive?
I am trying to use Vec::sort_unstable_by_key periodically. From my understanding, it is sorting-in-place; So it moves elements within the vector.
I wonder:
If the size of the element is large, will it becomes expensive? In that case, will wrapping large data in pointers like Rc and then store pointers in the vector helps?

You'd want Box in that case, not Rc. And yes, this can become expensive, but whether it's more expensive than the indirection introduced by box is something you can't predict, you'll need to measure that. Also, if you're sorting something periodically, using a BTreeSet might be another option.

Box! Yes, definitely better than Rc. Unfortunately, in my case the "key functions" to sort are changing. I believe BTreeSet does not work with that.

Copying memory takes, very rougly estimated, around 0.04 nanoseconds per byte. Source.
A full cache miss to RAM takes around 65 nanoseconds. Source.
Both of these are very rough estimates but should give you an idea of the difference in order of magnitudes.
If you use indirection via a Box or a Rc, swapping will become very fast, but actually checking the contents to compare them will require fetching a distant area from memory which which is more likely to miss the cache. Also you need to check the data much more often than you swap objects to sort an array.
Thus the data needs to be extremely large before using a Box or Rc becomes worth it. I generally start considering using indirection if the object is more than a few kilobytes in size. Optimization is very complex and the only way to really know which is faster for your specific use case is to measure.

Instead of Box, you can use indices to a Vec, this will be both cacheable and fast to sort.

You mean using another Vec holds indices to the original Vec to be sorted; Then sort the indices vector based on the elements stored in the original vector the indices point to? But will check the value in the original vector by indices faster than Box?

@ChayimFriedman You can also use Vec<&T> for a similar effect. It will theoratically increase speed since the objects will be stored close together thus increase the chance of a cache hit, at the cost of allocating an entire new vector. You'd need to measure to see if it's worthwhile.

And if you're going the indices-vector route, take a look sort_by_cached_key which does that dance for you. (But it also requires having a sort key, and will store the key in the temporary vector as well.)

@yushizhao Yes, it will, because the elements will be close and fetched together from memory.

@mousetail You link sources for your numbers, but they don't back your numbers at all? Cache miss to RAM: 65 ns. memcopy: 17 GB/s → 0.06 ns / B. Also, the numbers aren't super relevant, there's no automatic implication of Box → full cache miss or Vec → linear access, no cache misses. Lastly: Depending on object size and access patterns, the integer-index-Vec approach might not provide much benefit over Box at all, cache-locality wise.

@Caesar Numbers Of course Box doesn't guarentee a cache miss, and neither does contiguous storage guarentee a cache hit. I never claimed it would. It's simply more likely.
